# Azure Table Storage: How do you group AND and OR Queries Utilizing NodeJS Library?

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

Utilizing the manual editor in Azure Storage Explorer I can create the following query that returns the results I want from the Azure Table Storage:

```
TYPE eq 'MYTYPE' and (PartitionKey eq '1' or PartitionKey eq '2')
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this with the NodeJS library.

The following code:

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const svc = new azure.TableService();
var azureQuery = new azure.TableQuery().where("TYPE eq 'MYTYPE'").or("PartitionKey eq '1'").or("PartitionKey eq '2'")
```

Is equivalent to the query:

```
TYPE eq 'MYTYPE' or PartitionKey eq '1' or PartitionKey eq '2'
```

Likewise I can do the following:

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const svc = new azure.TableService();
var azureQuery = new azure.TableQuery().where("TYPE eq 'MYTYPE'").and("PartitionKey eq '1'").or("PartitionKey eq '2'")
```

But that results in the query:

```
 TYPE eq 'MYTYPE' and PartitionKey eq '1' or PartitionKey eq '2'
```

How do I do the equivalent of parenthesis from the NodeJS library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I known, the simple way is like the code below based on my understanding for the [`TableQuery`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tablequery.js#L37) object.

[image]

```
var filter = "TYPE eq 'MYTYPE' and ( PartitionKey eq '1' or PartitionKey eq '2' )"
var azureQuery = new azure.TableQuery().where(filter)
```

It works fine.

Comment: I don't know what I messed up when I tried that before, but I must have had some stupid typo. I tried it again this morning and it worked for me. Thanks for your help!